# Is CLLocationManagerDelegate didFailError always callback error is CLError?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

In swift, the method of `CLLocationManagerDelegate` `didFailWithError` error is always CLError? If yes, any reference?

> Discussion: Invoked when an error has occurred. Error types are
>   defined in "CLError.h".

Does it mean I can convert error to `LAError` anytime?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        guard let error = error as? CLError else {
            // Never?
            return
        }
    }
```

And `LAError`...

Comment: chekc your question tag.. some grammer and/or wording issues confuge people on what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Why would you be able to cast it to an `LAError`.- Why would a local authenticatoin framework error be delivered to a Core Location delegate method?

Comment: have you taken a look at `CLError.h` file? What error types does it include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below legit reference for the error when CLLocationManager object is not able to retrieve the location. The Discussions part also have some examples also in the reference that which error will be received in different scenarios :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423786-locationmanager

Hope this helps you!!